# Remove Black Border From Scanned Image c#

Tags: c#, image, border

I have an application that scan Images from scanner but some scanners put a black border around the saved image.
How can I remove that black border?
Thanks so much for your participation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve had good luck in the past process images using the Magick.NET library.  It’s available on [Codeplex](https://magick.codeplex.com/) or you can install it using NuGet in Visual Studio.  Documentation for the library is a little sparse, but it’s served me well in the past.

Depending upon the exact nature of the images you’re dealing with, you might be able to do something as simple as crop off the edges where the border is and then add a white (or whatever color; I just assumed that you were scanning text documents or something) border to bring the image back up to a standardized size.  If having a standardized size doesn’t matter, then of course you can just leave the image cropped.  If that sounds like a viable solution, here’s some code that should accomplish what you need:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(@"path_to_original"))
{
    int width = image.Width, height = image.Height;
    image.Crop(width - 800, height - 800);

    //if the image needs to be brought back up to a standarized size
    image.BorderColor = new ColorRGB(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    image.Border(100, 100);

    image.Write(@"path_to_cropped_image_with_no_more_black_border_around_it");
}
```

You will, of course need to add your own values for just how much width you need to crop off/add back in.